# Cant onClick event do <li> tag React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a sideBar that opens when I click on a button and i have `<li>` items there.

I want do add an onCLick event to those items but, onClick event fires when page is loaded and when ever I click on `<nav className={drawClass}>` elements.

Any information is helpful, thank you.

```
const Sidedraw = props => {
  let drawClass = "sideDraw";
  if (props.show) {
    drawClass = "sideDraw open";
  }
  return (
    <nav className={drawClass}>
      <ul>
        <li className="matches" onclick={console.log("work work")}>
          Pro matches
        </li>
        <li className="matches">Public mathes</li>
        <li className="matches">Players</li>
        <li className="matches">Teams</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Comment: `onClick` (not `onclick`) expects a function reference. You need to either pass it a function that logs out, or use something inline (eh) like `onClick={() => console.log('works')}`

Comment: [Read about it in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the onClick should be a function reference.

Also, you will likely get a warning with the current code:

> Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners

You should place an interactive element (anchor, button, etc.) within the list item.

```
<ul>
  <li className="matches">
    <button onClick={() => console.log('work work')}>Pro matches</button>
  </li>
  <li className="matches">Public mathes</li>
  <li className="matches">Players</li>
  <li className="matches">Teams</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re setting the onClick to the *result* of the `console.log` call, not the function itself. You want:

```
onClick={() => console.log("work work")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for [Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Also, you might want to move your click handler into its own function so that you can easily add it to all nav items.

```js
const Sidedraw = props => {
  let drawClass = "sideDraw";
  if (props.show) {
    drawClass = "sideDraw open";
  }
  function clickHandler(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target)
  }
  return (
    <nav className={drawClass}>
      <ul>
        <li className="matches" onClick={clickHandler}>Pro matches</li>
        <li className="matches" onClick={clickHandler}>Public mathes</li>
        <li className="matches" onClick={clickHandler}>Players</li>
        <li className="matches" onClick={clickHandler}>Teams</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mm5wbp)

Answer (score 0):

you must add clickeventhandler to each element you want to perform some actions.

```js
<li className="matches" onClick={handleValueChange}>Pro matches</li>
```

and you must add that function ie

```
handleValueChange = (e) => {
    // ...
}
```